# Given n jobs and m processors. Use Chernoff Bound to determine upper and lower bounds on jobs to be completed of processing time?

Tags: probability

In textbook by Mitzenmacher and Upfal, Probability and Computing we have question in chapter 4 about Chernoff Bound.

> (Mitzenmacher and Upfal) 4.17 Suppose that we have n jobs to distribute among m processors. For simplicity, we assume that m divides n. A job takes 1 step with probability p and k>1 steps with probability 1-p. Use Chernoff Bound to determine upper and lower bounds (that hold with high probability) on when all jobs will be completed if we randomly assign exactly n/m jobs to each processor.

To make question simple, just assume we have one machine and n jobs. Now, I can define a random variable X_i which is the event where jobs taks i steps. So, X_i = p if k=1, and X_i= (1-p) if k>1. How would you solve such kind of question, if you give hint it would be enough because the random variable that I defined is still not applicable for Chernoff Bound; because it is not Poisson trails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X_i$ be an indicator random variable such that
$$
X_i = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{ the $i$-th job takes $k$ steps} \\
0 & \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
and $T$ be the completion of all jobs. Define
$$
S = \sum_{i=1}^n \left\{k\cdot [X_i=1] + 1\cdot [X_i = 0]\right\} = n + (k -
 1)\cdot\sum_{i=1}^n X_i
$$
where $[X_i = 1]$ equals $1$ if $X_i = 1$ and $0$ otherwise; similarly for $[X_i = 0]$. Note that $S$ is the time to complete all jobs using one machine. Therefore,
$$
\frac{S}{m} \leq T \leq S \tag{$\spadesuit$}
$$
By applying Chernoff bound, you can find bounds for $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ (and thus $S$) with high probability.